# How to set permissions what users can see (drives, folders) on opensuse 12.1?

Tags: permissions, users, opensuse

I have a several users on one machine and its needed to specify which user can access (read & write) specified folders and/or mounted drives.

First of all, one user shouldn't see a `home/<%username%>/` of another user.

edit:
I'll try to explain very simply: 
Lets say we have two users: steven and john. Both of them have some private data under their directories: john/private, john/Desktop, steven/private, steven/Desktop.
I would like to prevent that steven can access (read or write) under john/ dir and prevent john to read/write under steven/dir.

i'm hope so I'm clear enough :)

Comment: Unless you create a virtual machine for each user, there will always be some resources that will show that there are multiple users on the system.  For example, even if you were to create a dynamic chroot(1) system, doing a `ps` would still show that there are other users with their UIDs and GIDs.  You might get a better answer if you clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: mr. @Arcege, I have edited my question, hope it's better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, in general, not possible on Unix. If being able to see the directory but not listing the contents is acceptable (it probably is), then set the mode so that the user affected does not have the read bit set on their modes for that directory (`700` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I see is to give each user their own group (becoming standard already on various linux boxes) and setting the default umask for the system to 027 (maps to g-w,o-rwx) in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/login.defs` (for PAM).  Lastly, change the users' "private" directories to 0700 (u=rwx,go=) and their home directory to 0750 (u=rwx,g=rx,o=).

This will still allow your users to control his/her permissions, but the default will prevent other users from seeing the contents.